# Show box only on edit post

Tags: post-editor

I've made a video custom post type and on the edit page I've placed a meta box where I display a shortcode associated to the post, to make it easier for the user.

However, I wish the shortcode and/or the box to be visible on the edit post page only and not on the new post page, where it's not yet relevant - what am I looking for here? I have this nagging feeling I've done this/something similar before but just can't think of what to search for.

ETA:
This is what I did with the help I got below, might be useful to someone else too:

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'my_video_add_custom_box' );
function my_video_add_custom_box() {
    if (get_post_status( $post->ID ) != 'auto-draft') {
        add_meta_box(
            'my_video_shortcode_custom_box',
            __( 'Shortcode', 'my_video' ),
            'my_video_shortcode_custom_box',
            'my_video', 'side', 'default'
        );
    }
}
```

Works like a charm, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the post status using get_post_status( $ID ) and then display the html code according to the status. ( i.e ) You could simply use if else condition in your php template file to display different content based on the post status. I think new posts have auto-draft status. [get_post_status](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_status)
codex should be helpful.

Comment: Thanks, I never would have thought to look for that. Will add my finished code to my question above.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution, incorrectly posted as an edit to the question, give me an "undefined variable" `Notice` for `$post`. It works because the chain of function calls triggered by `get_post_status` ultimately, if all else fails, [assumes the `global` variable `$post`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.7.1/src/wp-includes/post.php#L388).

A better solution would be to move the conditional out of registration function and into the callback, which is passed the `$post` variable by the WordPress core.

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'my_video_add_custom_box' );
function my_video_add_custom_box() {
  add_meta_box(
      'my_video_shortcode_custom_box',
      __( 'Shortcode', 'my_video'),
      'my_video_shortcode_custom_box',
      'my_video', 
      'side', 
      'default'
  );
}

function my_video_shortcode_custom_box($post) {
  if (get_post_status( $post->ID ) != 'auto-draft') {
    // your box code
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm the first to admit, I still find it confusing to know when the $post variable is sent along or not, but I guess the first two rows should have looked like this instead: `add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'my_video_add_custom_box', 10, 2 );`
`function my_video_add_custom_box($post_type, $post) {` to make sure the $post is sent along. I could move the conditional but then I'd be left with an empty box and not without a box which was what I was after.

Comment: Btw, I wasn't sure where else to post the code as it's not a new answer or full code but just a little snippet to show what I did. And it worked for me, whether it should have or not.